# How to resize background of imagebutton clickable space

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

[image]I have a custom imagebutton and I only want the custom imagebutton to be clickable. Currently all of the surrounding area of the button is "clickable" and initiates the new activity. I want to minimize this "clickable background" space. How can I do it?

```
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/start_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/flashcardbutton" />
```

Comment: Can you post your xml and possibly a picture so we have more of an idea of what you have? Also, I assume you're using `wrap_content` for the `width`?

Comment: @codeMagic yes I am using wrap_content for both attributes.

Comment: Your `Button` is going to be clickable. If there's space in the `ImageButton` that you don't want to be clickable then you need to trim that out of your `Button`. If its a parent `layout` that is being clickable that you don't want then we need to see that

Comment: @codeMagic I have already cleared the background of the image.

Comment: a proper screenshot would explain more of the issue, can you please?

Comment: alright done sorry the picture is big

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this though but just a guess.. is it possible to use :

```
public void getHitRect(Rect outRect) {
    outRect.set(getLeft()-10, getTop()-10, getRight()-10, getBottom()-10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well giving a shot to the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) I found that `ImageButton` has a method with this signature

```
public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityNodeInfo info)
```

and [AccessibilityNodeInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html#setBoundsInScreen%28android.graphics.Rect%29) class has this method

```
public void setBoundsInScreen (Rect bounds)
```

so with this said 
I think you should achieve what you are trying to do, this in adition to @Sushil answer should make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this may helps:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/start_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" <!-- Here is the thing you need -->
    android:src="@drawable/flashcardbutton" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I think this was definitely my fault. Even thhough I made the background "transparent" The frame was still bigger than my image. I just had to use photoshop and crop the image. Thank you all!

Comment: Your issue is that you didn't really need to use an ImageButton, you want to use a regular Button with an image replacing its background. check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use an ImageButton with your image as the 'src,' you want to use a regular button with your image as the 'background' otherwise it imitates a button with padding and what not even though you nullify the background image...

Use your original image like this:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/start_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/flashcardbutton" />
```